# How can I create and modify multiple SVGs dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg

I am adding multiple SVGs dynamically, then modifying each of them.  Without an event listener, the map was not being seen.  Now, however, the event listener appears to create multiple instances of the last loop, instead of one for each loop, only the last instance gets modified, but multiple times with the same `mygroup,svgID`.

```
for (var i=0; i<path.length; i++) {
    var mygroup = path[i], svgID = "svgMap" + i
    const iSVG = document.createElement("object")
    document.getElementById("summary-mygroup").appendChild(iSVG)
    iSVG.id = svgID
    iSVG.type = "image/svg+xml"
    iSVG.data = "Maps/mygroup_basemap.svg"
    iSVG.addEventListener('load', function(){
        createMap(mygroup,svgID)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR:

use `const` instead of `var`

```js
const mygroup = path[i], divID = "div" + i, svgID = "svgMap" + i
```

---

What you are seeing is due to `function()` using `mygroup`, `divID` , and `svgID` form the loop's scope which keeps updating until the functions execute (all with the latest value). This happens because the same variable is used.

##### `var` and `const`/`let` do not behave the same

`var` scopes to the function, whereas `let`/`const` are scoped to the block. (`var` also gets hoisted, but that's less related to the issue)

so if you run:

```js
for (var i=0; i < 3; i++){
    var b = i
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(b)},1)//  2,2,2
}
console.log("B:", b) //  2
```

you wouldn't expect to have `console.log("B:", b)` run without an error, but it does, because the scope of var exists outside of the function.

whereas if you use `let` or `const`

```js
for (var i=0; i < 3; i++){
  let b = i;
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(b)},1)//  0,1,2
}
console.log("B:", b)  //  throws error
```

you will have expected behaviour, including an error on the console.log

And because it is a function-vs-block-scope issue, you could move the entire functionality inside a function and call it, which will lock the scope to the function:

```js
for (var i=0; i < 3; i++){
  (function(){
    var b = i
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(b)},1)//  0,1,2
  })()
}
```

Comment: more reading material re. differences between var/const/let
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript